# Render swf to png or other format?

Tags: php, flash, server-side, gnash

I need to render the final state of a `SWF` passing flash vars parameters.

Let's say I use the `var text="Some text"`, and the swf shows the text over a static background. I need to render this to a png file, I've tried with gnash but with no luck so far, here is an example of the command I'm running.

> gnash --screenshot last --screenshot-file imagename.png -1 -r1 test.swf -P "FlashVars=parameter=text"

The problem is that this renders the background image, without the text that's supposed to be over it.

<strike>I can't use `swftools` because I don't control the server and they don't want to install the software.</strike>

Now I'm allowed to install this on the server.

Comment: Extra info: Apparently gnash is not sending the flashvars to the swf, in my example:
`gnash loaderInfo.swf --param "FlashVars=userName=permadi"`
Shows nothing,

As html code with the exact same flashvar it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm do you have access to the swf code?
If so you could for instance save the contents of the stage to a bitmap and then save as png/jpeg which you can transfer to a server side or serving it directly to the client for download.

Look at this post for example code [Trying to capture stage area using BitmapData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450381/trying-to-capture-stage-area-using-bitmapdata)

Comment: That would be a solution but I can't run the `SWF` file from the client side, because we are trying to accomplish this as a workaround for iOS systems. Also i'm editing the question, I'm allowed to use `SWFTools` now :)